# Getting list of invited Facebook friends with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-apps, facebook-invite, facebook-friends

I've adapted Facebook's example code to let me show the list of invited users... but I can't get a list.

Can someone help me with the right syntax to get a list of invited friend?

This is what i've come with so far:

```
$invite = $facebook->api('friends.invite');
$result = $facebook->api('/me/friends/','invite');
```

Or i try to connect FQL

```
$_friends = $facebook->api(array(
      'method' => 'fql.query',
      'query' => 'SELECT sender_uid FROM apprequest WHERE request_id = $id'
    ));
```

I can confirm that BEFORE this point in my code, 
things were fine: I'm connected to Facebook with a valid session 
and I can get my info and dump it.